# $rootScope.$on called multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `$rootScope.$emit('driver-loader');` once my webservice finished getting data. This is the only place 'driver-loader' gets emitted. Once I do...

```
var watchDriverLoader = $rootScope.$on('driver-loaded', function(){
        console.log('loaded');
        watchDriverLoader = null;
    });
```

...inside my controller, that console.log gets called multiple times, sometimes even 4-5 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to destroy `$rootScope.$on` manually.

```
var watchDriverLoader = $rootScope.$on('driver-loaded', function(){
    console.log('loaded');
});
$scope.$on('$destroy', watchDriverLoader);
```